# AWK / Linux script calculations from a text file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, awk

I wrote an AWK script that read files and multiplies rows by columns and sum them up. I want to pass several files (any number of files) as an argument in awk script at a time e.g. A.txt, B.txt, C.txt. I want the AWK script to give me sum of rows and columns. I always want to skip first 5 columns from each text file.

Each text file can have any number of columns. There can be several text files inside a folder.

I want to run as:

```
awk -f foo.awk A.txt B.txt C.txt
```

e.g.

If there are 3 different files A.txt, B.txt, C.txt, sum up multiplication of rows and columns from each 3 files.

Output should be:

```
No of columns in A.txt: count of columns in A.txt with first 5 columns ignored
No of columns in B.txt: count of columns in B.txt with first 5 columns ignored
No of columns in C.txt: count of columns in C.txt with first 5 columns ignored
Sum of A.txt: rows in A.txt*columns in A.txt
Sum of B.txt: rows in B.txt*columns in B.txt
Sum of C.txt: rows in C.txt*columns in C.txt
Total Sum: A+B+C
```

Below is (sort of pseudo-code) what I have got so far for foo.awk (it is not working with multiple files):

```
#!/bin/gawk -f

BEGIN { rows=0; columns=0 }
{
    FS="\t";
    if(/^#COLS/) {
            column=NF-5; #skip first 5 columns
            columns+=column
    }
    if (!/^#/){
            rows++;
            files[FILENAME]++;
    }
}
END {
    for (fname in files) {
            printf ("%'24d rows in %s\n",files[fname],fname);
    }
            printf("No of columns in A.txt= %'d\n", columnsA);
            printf("No of columns in B.txt= %'d\n", columnsB);
            printf("No of columns in C.txt= %'d\n", columnsC);
            sum=columns*rows; # multiply no of rows by column in each file and add them up 
            printf( "Sum of A.txt %d\n", sumA);
            printf( "Sum of B.txt %d\n", sumB);
            printf( "Sum of C.txt %d\n", sumC);   
            printf( "Total sum is %d\n", sum_of_A+B+C);  
}
```

e.g.

```
A.txt:
#ignore this line -- pattern does not match
#ignore this line -- pattern does not match
#COLS   A       B       C       D       E       F       G       H       I 
row1    1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9
row2    1       3       3       4       5       6       7       8       9
row3    1       3       3       4       5       6       7       8       9

B.txt:
#ignore this line -- pattern does not match
#ignore this line -- pattern does not match
#COLS   A       B       C       D       E       F       G       H        
row1    1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       
row2    5       3       3       4       6       6       7       8       
row3    8       3       3       4       5       6       7       8       

C.txt:
#ignore this line -- pattern does not match
#ignore this line -- pattern does not match
#COLS   A       B       C       D       E       F       G       H       I       J
row1    1       2       3       3       5       6       7       8       9       2
row2    7       3       3       4       5       6       7       8       9       7
row3    9       3       3       4       5       6       7       8       9       6
row4    9       3       3       4       5       6       7       8       9       6

output:

No of columns in A.txt: 5
No of columns in B.txt: 4
No of columns in C.txt: 6
Sum of A.txt: 3*5=15
Sum of B.txt: 3*4=12
Sum of C.txt: 4*6=24
Total Sum: 12+9+20 = 51
```

Thank you.

Comment: not very familiar with awk, but I think you need to use filewise constructs  BEGINFILE and ENDFILE, which might be gawk specific...

Comment: @Sundeep It's gawk specific, see [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/BEGINFILE_002fENDFILE.html) - but IMO the best solution if gawk is available.

Comment: @BenjaminW. thanks for clarifying.. just noticed that OP used `#!/bin/gawk -f`

Comment: Please give a couple of sample files and expected output. This is way too confusing.

Comment: Updated with examples, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with plain `awk` you can do this

```
$ awk '!/^#/{cols[FILENAME]=NF-5; 
             rows[FILENAME]++} 
         END{for(f in cols) print "No of columns in " f, cols[f]; 
             for(f in cols) 
               {r=rows[f];
                c=cols[f];
                sum+=r*c; 
                sumstr=sumstr?sumstr"+"r*c:r*c; 
                print "Sum of "f ":",r "x" c "=" r*c} 
             print "Total Sum: ", sumstr, "=", sum}' {A,B,C}.txt

No of columns in C.txt 6
No of columns in B.txt 4
No of columns in A.txt 5
Sum of C.txt: 4x6=24
Sum of B.txt: 3x4=12
Sum of A.txt: 3x5=15
Total Sum:  24+12+15 = 51
```

There is a mismatch in number of columns, are you skipping 5 or 6.  Also note that the order of entries is not preserved, can be fixed with `gawk` sorted-in, or with little extra coding as below...

```
$ awk 'FNR==1{order[++k]=FILENAME} 
        !/^#/{cols[FILENAME]=NF-5; rows[FILENAME]++} 
          END{for(i=1;i<=k;i++) print "No of columns in " order[i], cols[order[i]]; 
              for(i=1;i<=k;i++) {f=order[i];r=rows[f];c=cols[f];sum+=r*c; sumstr=sumstr?sumstr"+"r*c:r*c; print "Sum of "f ":",r "x" c "=" r*c} 
              print "Total Sum: ", sumstr, "=", sum}' {A,B,C}.txt

No of columns in A.txt 5
No of columns in B.txt 4
No of columns in C.txt 6
Sum of A.txt: 3x5=15
Sum of B.txt: 3x4=12
Sum of C.txt: 4x6=24
Total Sum:  15+12+24 = 51
```

Comment: thank you. But your script does not look for #COLS or # pattern. Can you please update it?

Comment: does it matter if all the rows have the same number of columns?  If not, row * columns won't give you the number of elements anyway.

Comment: Oh, you're skipping rows too!

Comment: I am trying to get total number of columns in each file A.txt, B.txt etc. I want to multiply No of rows in each file by number of column in each file. Finally I want to sum rows and columns from each file.

Comment: For the inputs I used and the generated output, what information do you think is missing or incorrect?  If so please create a minimal input set and expected output in your original post so that other people won't be confused either.

Comment: upvote++ I'll just drop my mess with `ENDFILE`s and stuff.

Comment: @karakfa this is my first AWK project and would appreciate if you could update your script? I can give you a right answer. Thank a lot.

Comment: @karakfa it is working thank you. How do I put it inside foo.awk file? I need to run it as a script.

Comment: copy/paste the contents between the single quotes (excluding the quotes) into a text file, let's say `count.awk`.  Now you can invoke it with `awk -f count.awk file1...`